# What is the best description for Encapsulation to give in an interveiw?

Tags: oop, encapsulation

I know all the `OOP concepts` to code them and show and explain to the depth.

I have been thinking what might be the best explanation I can give for a interview on `What is encapsulation question.?`

I can simply write a code and show encapsulation. When that Q asked the explanation I would give is How we do encapsulation. But What is encapsulation. and to which extent we have to tell about encapsulation when the question asked? . Do we have to say all the `advantages/disadv` and `when to use` , `examples` and how the `security` comes to issue, `flexibilty`. DO we have to tell `all these` for this one question? What is encapsulation?.

And if I give whole this explanation is it like I am `talking too much?` What would `interviewer prefer`? a `short answer?`

Letting them know we know everything on encapsulation is needed? it is like a I am lecturing them on Encapsulation right? .

I probably can do that to survive for Other concepts. But encapsulation can explain widely just like I learn it to the depth.

And how in real world encapsulation shows up.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interview technique. Interviews are just a chat with a purpose.

Comment: @EdHeal Interviews are as important as we learn all these concepts. We do all to pass an interview and go to a job. unless why we learn all these things? Interview can be just a chat if the interviewer is a relation of you.

Comment: It is a chat - It is not a one-way street. They are trying to find out about you (your abilities, how you fit in with the others etc) and you are finding out about them. You can end up with "passing" an interview and being offered the job. But if you have not found out about the company during the interview you made take the job and make a bad choice

Comment: Do you know even `Interview` itself is an example of `Encapsulation`.

Comment: @Rahul interviews is?

Comment: Yes indeed, I mean the interview process. Think a bit and you will understand as why.

Answer (score -4):

encapsulation  is a hidden the background details

Example

```
int a=1;
int b=2;

int c=a+b;  /// here a and b value hidden, its called as encapsulation
```

Comment: This is not at all an example of encapsulation.